# ACCEPT ELEMENTS IN A LINKED LIST IN ASCENDING ORDER,but the display function prints the smallest number instead of the whole linked list

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

Accept elements in the linked list in ascending order and then i want to print the whole linked list but it prints only the first number and gives a run time error.similar code is available in data structures in c.
here t=start so that when the element less than the start node  is entered then the address of the starting node is saved in the t pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//creation of a linked list
struct node 
{
int data;
struct node *next;
};
void display(struct node *start); //function to display Linked list
int main()
{
struct node *start,*t,*r;
start=NULL;
t=start;

int n,num,i;

print("\n enter the number of elements");
scanf("%d",&num);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        printf("\n enter the %d element",i);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    r=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));//
    r->data=n;

    if(start==NULL || start->data>n)//if the element id the first element or the element is less than the current element
        {
        start=r;
        start->next=t;
        }
        else
        {
            t=start;
        while(t!=NULL)
        {
            if(t->data<n && (t->next==NULL || t->next->data>n))//element has to added in the end or else it should be added between the following elements
            {
                r->next=t->next;
                t->next=r;
            }
            t=t->next;
        }
        }
    }
    display(start);
}
void display(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *display;
    display=start;
    while(display!=NULL)
    {
        print("%d ",display->data);
        display=display->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: More debugger, less shouting:(

Comment: Could you properly format the code and post run time error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

as your description suggests you have an issue when the inputed value is lower then the list head value, you want to place the allocated node at the start of the list and verify that this node now points to the previous head:

```
if( start == NULL || start->data > n )//if the element id the first element or the element is less than the current element
{
    r->next = start; //1
    start=r; //2
    //start->next=t; //3
}
```

1. your newly allocated node `r` should now point to the next element which was previously your `start`
2. now you should move your `start` pointer to the head of the list which is `r`

your mistake:

in each loop iteration `t` will always point to NULL, due to the `t=t->next;' and 'while(t!=NULL)'.

in that case every time your `if` evaluates to `true` (current value should be placed at the start of the list), you are effectivly creating a new list where that node is the head.